# Dynamically Add and Remove stack panel

Tags: .net, wpf, stackpanel, wrappanel

[image]

I have one `WrapPanel` (with green background) inside of a `ListBox`(with gray background).

I am trying to dynamically add a `StackPanel` multiple times (by clicking on the button below given image) in the `WrapPanel`.

The `StackPanel` contains a `Button` which has Content “X”. I want to remove individual `StackPanel` objects (with orange background) when this button is clicked.

**How can it be worked out?**

Comment: How are the StackPanels defined? If you are going to be generating them dynamically in code, you will have to be able to get the contents for them. There's a lot of ways to do this, but it is hard to tell what you are looking for.

Comment: straight forward.....just remove "stack panel" by clicking Button at top-right corner of it......"stack-pantel + button" button was added dynamically...at run time......

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Data Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) & [Data Templating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx) + [Commanding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308.aspx)

Your question is kind of extensive. The basic outline is to create bindable collections, data template them, and remove the clicked item from it using a command or event.

Example of DataTemplating using an ItemsControl that internally uses a WrapPanel for the layout:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DpData}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <!-- The content goes here, X-Button will be overlayed -->
                <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                        Content="X" Click="RemoveItem_Click"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

```
// Does not need to be a dependency property.
public static readonly DependencyProperty DpDataProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("DpData", typeof(ObservableCollection<Employee>), typeof(MainWindow), new UIPropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<Employee>()));
public ObservableCollection<Employee> DpData
{
    get { return (ObservableCollection<Employee>)GetValue(DpDataProperty); }
    set { SetValue(DpDataProperty, value); }
}
```

```
// For simplicity i use an event instead of a command.
private void RemoveItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = (FrameworkElement)sender;
    var emp = (Employee)button.DataContext;
    DpData.Remove(emp);
}
```

If you do it like this you should of course not add a panel upon add-button click but a data item to the collection. The panel will be generated automatically.

Comment: actually i am new to WPF so...could you show me...how to use <ItemControl></ItemControl>  in ListBox

Comment: You can just add it like you would add the wrap panel, it basically extends the wrap panel.

Comment: @H.B,  here,...as much instance of "Employee" i will store in "DpData"...that much button i will see on <ItemControl></ItemControl> at Run Time....Is it right or wrong?

Comment: For every element in the list (`DpData`) a template will be created, and every template includes a button.

Comment: @H.B, hello H.B thanks for replying....   here i have put Above XAML code in my "mainwindow.xaml" and "DpData" property and "DpDataProperty " in the "mainwindow.xaml.cs"....and in the "mainWindow_Loaded" event i have puted below code    [ DpData.Add(new       Employee("pritesh0", "abad0", 22));  ]
           ....Problem is though i am not getting "BUTTON"..in ItemControl........  Thanks...........

Comment: Since you said that you are new to WPF i recommend that you read the articles i linked to at the top of my answer. Working through them might take a while but it is key to using WPF efficiently. If you follow the examples given you should be able to make sense of my answer sooner or later. My answer is not something a beginner should try right away, especially since i did not mention how and where i set the `DataContext` which is needed to make the binding in the `ItemsSource` work. Anyway, read those articles and play with bindings in test-applications until you are comfortable using them.

Comment: i have combine the one article at http://www.galasoft.ch/mydotnet/articles/article-2007041201.aspx and code you have suggest .....and i have got my solution....thanks a lot for support.........

Answer (score 0):

This is the final code..........

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="itemsTemplate">
        <!-- This might also be included in a UserControl -->
        <Border Width="200" Height="200" CornerRadius="10,10,10,10" Margin="4,4,0,0" Padding="4,4,4,4">
            <Border.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0.5" StartPoint="0,0.5">
                    <GradientStop Color="AliceBlue" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="Bisque" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Border.Background>
            <Grid >
                <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="30" Height="20"  Content="X" Background="Red" Click="Remove_Click"></Button>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="10,10" Height="20"  ></TextBox>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding City}" Margin="10,10" Height="20" ></TextBox>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Age}" Margin="10,10" Height="20"></TextBox>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Count}" Margin="10,10" Height="20" ></TextBox>
                </WrapPanel>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl 

              Width="Auto"
              Height="Auto"
              ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=mainWindow, Path=EmployeeCollection}"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource itemsTemplate}"  Background="Aqua">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
    <Button Content="Add" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="487,287,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Add_Click" />
</Grid>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace DynamicAddRemovePanel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Employee> employeeCollection = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();

        public ObservableCollection<Employee> EmployeeCollection
        {
            get
            {
                return this.employeeCollection;
            }
            set
            {
                this.employeeCollection = value;
            }
        }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }




        public class Employee
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string City { get; set; }
            public int Age { get; set; }
            public static int Count { get; set; }
            public Employee()
            {
                Count++;
            }
            public Employee(string nameArg, string cityArg, int ageArg)
            {
                this.Name = nameArg;
                this.City = cityArg;
                this.Age = ageArg;
                Count++;
           }
        }

        private void Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            employeeCollection.Add(new Employee("Pritesh","Abad",22));
        }
        private void Remove_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var emp = (sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext as Employee;
            employeeCollection.Remove(emp);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Good job on putting that together; just some advice on your member declarations: For collections you normally do not provide a public `set` accessor because you can just clear them instead, further you would make the field `readonly` to prevent that it is being overwritten internally, this is because the binding will break if you do (the bound control still watches an object which is no longer being used and to which no more references in code exist). Further if you change other properties and you want the UI to update you need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in their owning class.

Comment: @H.B, Thank you so much for your suggestion......i will bear in mind all this things.....here i did not have bother about all this thing just because of....i was out-put oriented...Thanks......

Comment: NOTE:  don't forgot to add  x:Name="mainWindow" inside <window .... x:Name="mainWindow" .....></window> because we have use it inside ItemSource property of ItemControl